# Fill the checkboxes from an array in PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

Everyone

My question is so clear I think:

I have an array of checkboxes in HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gruplar[]" value="<?=$deptId?>">
```

It takes "value" values from database ID's e.g. 1,4,5

I can get these values in an array variable named `$divided[]`. For example 1,4,5 selected and the array is: `$divided[0]=1,$divided[1]=4,$divided[2]=5`,

When I need to update the record of checkbox list, I want to get this checkbox list selected with these array values.

- Check the checkbox which has "value" of "1", "4" and "5" according to
  the elements of the array.

How can I do that in HTML mixed PHP context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gruplar[]" value="<?=$deptId?>"<?=(in_array($deptId,$divided))?' checked="checked":''?> />
```

This checks if the value of the checkbox (as given by $deptId, which I'm assuming is what you meant as you're echoing it for the value attribute) is in the array $divided. If it is, it echos markup to make the checkbox checked when it is rendered by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $checked = array(1, 4, 5);
    foreach ($all as $id) // $all is all checkboxes
    {
        sprintf('<input type="checkbox" name="gruplar[]" value="%d" %s>', $id, in_array($id, $checked) ? 'checked="checked"' : '');
    }
?>
```

Also, it's better to build meta array like this

```
array(
    //(int) id => (bool) checked
    1 => true,
    2 => false,
    ...
);
```

Then do:

```
foreach ($meta as $id => $checked)
{
   sprintf('<input type="checkbox" name="gruplar[]" value="%d" %s>', $id, $checked ? 'checked="checked"' : '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Update ur Checkbox Field will display the PHP if else condition for comparing two variables for mapping

```
if(in_array($depid,$divided)){
$checked = "checked='checked'";
}else{
$checked = "";
}

<input type="checkbox" name="gruplar[]" value="<?=$deptId?>" <?=$checked; ?>/>
```